# using spring validator framework how can I send back a dataset when validation fails

Tags: spring, validation

My application has a scenario, where email input is checked at the backend for duplication. I am using the spring validation framework for this purpose. If the email id exists , then i need to send back the list of existing customer names to the front end. How can I achieve this as the validator only allows to send back validation message along with the field names. 
Is the re anyway to handle this kind of scenario ?